# Hyperlink is complete when hovering with mouse, doesn't work when clicked

Tags: sharepoint, hyperlink, ms-word, ms-office

I am working with a word doc from Sharepoint that is filled with hyperlinks that have moved from one place to another. Word attempted to autoshift these links and it appears to have done a good job; when I hover over a hyperlink it shows me the full URL to the location of the document (pictured) but when I expand the hyperlink using Ctrl+F9 it shows the link quite differently.

How the link looks when I hover over it: "https://school.sharepoint.com/sites/Teachers/js/..."

How the link looks when I Alt+F9
"../Maths%201%20to%208%20ebooksledge%20Practise.pdf" (example links not real)

Why is my link appearing correctly upon hovering but when expanded it starts with '../' and cuts off half the link? Picture attached.
[Hovered and Expanded Pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FxfR.png)

Comment: The `..` directory is the parent directory of the current directory.  So, as an example, if the current directory was `//school.sharepoint.com/sites/Teachers` then `../abc/def/xxx.pdf` would be equivalent to `//school.sharepoint.com/sites/abc/def/xxx.pdf`.  Is that sort of what you are seeing?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, yes this being the directory turned out to be correct and it was working correctly, the links the client had inputted were just bad links even when non-abbreviated. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the result (as YowE3K suggested) in the link is a relative url (which saves room within the system).  There are a number of different ways to represent urls.  If we start with https:... Then we have a complete path and if you were to move the document, the link doesn't change or have context (If I email the document to someone, assuming they have access to the URL, it will work).  Having a relative URL is great for moving things around because assuming all the documents are in the same relative location, then if I move a top level folder, or change the name of the web site, the links will still work.
You can either leave it as is, assuming it's working or you can replace the link with the complete path.

Comment: Yes this turned out to be correct and was helpful in narrowing the issue down, thanks for the explanation.